# Stop AVAudioPlayer in another class

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I've searched multiple forums including this one, and cannot find a solution to my problem. I have a sound file set to play when my "IQTest" view controller loads. It plays fine, and I can stop the sound in "IQTest" view controller.

**IQTest.h**

```
@interface IQTest : UIViewController
{
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
@end
```

**IQTest.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IQTestBackgroundMusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* soundTrack=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
soundTrack.numberOfLoops = -1;
self.theAudio = soundTrack;
[theAudio play];
}
```

I want to stop playing the sound when a user presses the button in "IQTestQuestionThree"'s view controller, but when I try at stop the sound, it either keeps playing, or my app crashes. I've tried multiple ways, and have yet to find one to stop my sound.

**IQTestQuestionThree.m**

```
- (IBAction) question3Answer1
{
IQTest *IQTestAudio = [[IQTest alloc] init];
[IQTestAudio.theAudio stop];

iqScaryFace.hidden = NO;
homeButton.hidden = NO;
homeButtonLabel.hidden = NO;
answer1Button.hidden = YES;
answer2Button.hidden = YES;
answer3Button.hidden = YES;
answer4Button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Thank you for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) question3Answer1
{
    IQTest *IQTestAudio = [[IQTest alloc] init];
    [IQTestAudio.theAudio stop];
```

This code creates a brand new `IQTest` object (which is a `UIViewController` subclass -- and therefore has a confusing name), and then calls its `stop` method.

This brand-new `IQTest` object (maybe rename it `IQTestViewController`?) was just created -- it isn't the same object that started playing the sound. So you're expecting it to stop playing something it has no control over. (At least, I don't expect it to work, without seeing more code.)

> I want to stop playing the sound when a user presses the button in
>   "IQTestQuestionThree"'s view controller

How is the view hierarchy structured?

Is `IQTestQuestionThree` a view controller whose parent is `IQTest`? (Again, consider renaming `IQTestQuestionThree` to something like `IQTestQuestionThreeViewController`.) If so, you could use the [delegate pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) to have `IQTestQuestionThree` alert `IQTest` to stop playing the sound.

If your view controller hierarchy is more complex, and/or if there are other view controllers in other places that might want to stop playing the sound, consider creating a [model class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for sound playing to act as a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for playing sounds, instantiate that model class in your app delegate, and pass it along to all the view controllers that need to control audio.

(`UIViewController` subclasses, by convention, have "`ViewController`" as a suffix on their name. You'll find this is the case in Apple's source code. If you want to write your code for readability, you should follow conventions for what language in which you're writing as closely as possible.)

Comment: Forgive me for being an amateur, but when I try and switch "IQTestQuestionThree"'s inheritance from UIViewController, to "IQTest", I get an error.

"Cannot find interface declaration for 'IQTest', superclass of 'IQTestQuestionThree'".

Comment: @AaronChapman I'm sorry if I gave you the impression that's what I was suggesting. It's definitely not. I am merely saying you should consider *renaming* your classes to match Cocoa conventions, not necessarily change their inheritance structure.

Comment: Okay, I renamed all of my classes, and entered the right names in all of the connected files. Thanks for the tip. I still can't stop the sound though.

Comment: How would I call an instance of the "IQTestViewController" class itself? Instead of creating an entirely new instance of it that does nothing.

Comment: I GOT IT! OH THANK YOU SO MUCH! THANK YOU SO MUCH SHAGGY FROG! YOU'RE FANTASTIC!